# Pass environment variable from Gitlab docker executor to image

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In my test setup, I use a docker executor to run my builds. Almost all our projects run on one of the official node images (ie `node:6`).

By default, these official images come with a logging level set to output quite abit.

According to the official documentation, that can be disabled https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#verbosity

```
Verbosity

By default the Node.js Docker Image has npm log verbosity set to info instead 
of the default warn. This is because of the way Docker is isolated from the 
host operating system and you are not guaranteed to be able to retrieve the 
npm-debug.log file when npm fails.

When npm fails, it writes it's verbose log to a log file inside the container. 
If npm fails during an install when building a Docker Image with the docker 
build command, this log file will become inaccessible when Docker exits.

The Docker Working Group have chosen to be overly verbose during a build to 
provide an easy audit trail when install fails. If you prefer npm to be less 
verbose you can easily reset the verbosity of npm using the following 
techniques:

Dockerfile

If you create your own Dockerfile which inherits from the node image you can 
simply use ENV to override NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL.

FROM node
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
...

Docker Run

If you run the node image using docker run you can use the -e flag to override 
NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL.

$ docker run -e NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn node ...

NPM run

If you are running npm commands you can use --loglevel to control the 
verbosity of the output.

$ docker run node npm --loglevel=warn ...
```

But when I just reference the docker image from my `gitlab-ci.yml` file, like so:

```
image: node:6

test:
    script:
        - npm install
```

How can I pass the environment variable, to set the logging level, to my docker executor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As listed in the [gitlab-ci reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#variables), you can specify environment variables in the configuration file with the `variables` keyword. In your case this would be

```
image: node:6

test:
    variables:
        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL: warn
    script:
        - npm install
```

Alternatively you could add `--loglevel=warn` to all `node` commands in the script part of your CI configuration.